# How to change the image size of qrencode.encode?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, qr-code

I'm creating a QR code using the python library [qrencode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qrencode), which returns a tuple with a PIL 25x25 image size. How can I export it with a higher image size? Right now I'm exporting to PDF, zooming 1000% and manually from there...

```
import qrencode as qre

url = "http://some.url.com"
qrTuple = qre.encode(url)
qrPIL = qrTuple[2]

filename = 'filename.png'
qrPIL.save(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **.resize()** function:

Add this code to the end of your program:

```
big = qrPIL.resize((1024, 1024))
big.save("bigger.png")
big.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `qrencode` library is using PIL and just returns you an PIL Image, so you can use the PIL Image method resize to scale the image before saving. Here I use the nearest neighbor filter to resize, as it will not try to interpolate the pixels of the QR code, so it will not distort it and will retain the sharp lines.

```
from PIL import Image

qrPIL = qrPIL.resize((256, 256), Image.NEAREST) # 256 pixels x 256 pixels
qrPIL.save('resized.png')
```

Here is a complete list of [PIL Image methods](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) that you can use to transform your QR code after it is created.

Comment: where do I import Image from?

Comment: ah sorry, you can do `from PIL import Image`, updated the example I gave